# postgres server started but could not connect to server

Tags: postgresql, sinatra

After I lost all the data on my computer (had to have everything erased by the Apple store), I installed postgres on my Mac using Homebrew with the command `brew install postgres`. I then started the server (with confirmation that the server was started) and tried to create a database for a Sinatra project that uses postgres, using the command

```
createdb db_development
```

However, I got the following error:

```
    createdb: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

After searching online, I discovered that I might have to run the following initdb command

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
```

but when I did it, I got this message

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "braindead".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_CA.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

initdb: directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" exists but is not empty
If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
the directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" or run initdb
with an argument other than "/usr/local/var/postgres".
```

So, why might postgres have confirmed the server had started at the same time I got this error `could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory`, and how could I fix this?

the READ.me for the project said

```
bundle install
createdb db_development
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It either tries to connect to the postgres that comes with MacOS or PG environment variables are not set.
Try:
 `createdb -h localhost db_development`

these are [postgres environment variables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-envars.html) for postgres. Also [PostgresApp](http://postgresapp.com/) is a very convenient way to use Postgresql on Mac

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has a "unix_socket_directory" setting located in postgresql.conf
Please verify that this setting exists and that the directory itself exists, then restart your server. If it doesn't exist, set it to something like /var/run (or another directory that exists) and restart the server.